# Yarn. Как правильно обновить пакеты, не добавляя их в зависимости в package.json?

Tags: gulp, npm, yarn

После обновления "yarn upgrade" высвечивается warning:

```
gulp-imagemin > imagemin > globby > fast-glob > micromatch > snapdragon > base > mixin-deep@1.3.1: Critical bug fixed in v2.0.1, please upgrade to the latest version.
```

Что это за **mixin-deep**? Я его не устанавливал(он от самого yarn или не знаю откуда ещё), его нет в package.json. А теперь меня просят обновить его.
Написав yarn upgrade mixin-deep@^2.0.1 он появится как зависимость в package.json. А мне он там не нужен.

Как обновить его не добавляя в зависимость? (в плане моего json файла. У меня там конкретные пакеты нужные для разработчика, а это что то техническое)

Answer (score 1):

`mixin-deep@1.3.1` это зависимость зависимости зависимости ...

последняя версия `micromatch@4.0.2` не использует `snapdragon` который использует `mixin-deep`.

если посмотреть `package.json` в цепочке `gulp-imagemin > imagemin > globby > fast-glob > micromatch`, можно увидеть что `globby@9.2.0` использует `fast-glob@2.2.6`, а не `fast-glob@3.0.1`.

это проблема цепочки зависимости `gulp-imagemin > imagemin > globby`, т.к. `globby@9.2.0`  использует старую версию `fast-glob@2.2.6`, обращайтесь сюда https://github.com/sindresorhus/globby/issues

Comment: Спасибо, уже теплее. Помогите понять. 
1) Я обновляю yarn. 2) Обновляется всё по цепочке из описания ошибки "globby > fast-glob > micromatch > snapdragon > base >" 3) Пакеты самых "высоких уровней" типо gulp-imagmin начинают выдавать ошибки потому что пункт 2 и все их зависимости обновились, а они с ними не умеют работать. Так?
Получается что надо либо вручную подключать новый globby, либо ждать ,когда авторы пакетов gulp-imagmin пропатчат их под новый yarn, так?

Comment: Заходишь на сайт yarn там котики, там всё так позитивно и просто. Вот пакетик, вот json. Прописал, написал и готово. Здорово, правда? А на самом деле, обновил yarn и п..... и на сайте уже нет никаких объяснений как с этим разбираться.

Comment: @SergeyHarchenko  нужно ждать авторов `globby`